# How to export data programmatically to a lar file in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to export web content in liferay. The data is to be exported into a .lar file format.I tried with several methods like `exportData(),exportPortletInfoAsFile()` but could not export. I searched a lot in the source code but could not achieve the result. So please suggest some more methods or the way which I should use in order to achieve the same? Thanx in advance..

Comment: Why don't you answer Olafs question here first: [Could not export data programmatically in liferay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871707/could-not-export-data-programmatically-in-liferay)?

Comment: That question is also asked by me not Olaf

Comment: I meant the questions in the comments - instead of asking nearly the same question again and again.

Comment: I want to know - is it possible to programmatically export the web content in liferay? If yes , please give some ideas of how to do that.